# Showing sum of squared residuals is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

I have the model $$y_i = B_0+\sum\limits_{i=0}^pB_kX_{ik} + e_i$$
I'm looking to show the sum of squared residuals is zero if $p = (n-1)$. I have tried expanding it quite in depth and I haven't been able to come anywhere near a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If we write the model as $y= \beta X + \varepsilon$, then we have
$$SSR = \|\hat{\beta}X - y\|^2$$
If we have the same number of regressors as the number of observations, we have that $X$ is a square non-singular matrix, under the standard assumptions. Since
$$\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$$
we have that
$$\hat{\beta}X = (X'X)^{-1}X'Xy=y$$
plugging in yields
$$SSR=\|\hat{\beta}X-y\|^2=\|y-y\|^2=0$$

Comment: so the only requirement is that we have the same number of regressors as the number of observations? So in this case we are given that there are n error terms, therefore if p = n - 1 we have (n-1)+1 betas which will give us a total of n regressors and n observations making these assumptions hold true?

Comment: We also need to ensure that the observations are linearly independent.